# Using sockets in android without WiFi

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream, wifi

So the program I am attempting to create sends a packet of data to a server I created that is hosted on a linux box. It all works however it only seems to work when I have WiFi connection. Due to the nature of my project, I need to find a way to use send packets to the server without using WiFi, thus using mobile data.

Is there a way to do this?

```
            connection = new Socket(IP, port);

            out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();

            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            out.writeObject(new Packet("General Information"));

            Packet = (Packet) in.readObject();
```

This is the code that I use for sending packets to my server. I use the permission for Internet in my manifest.xml. Is there a different permission I need to use in order to bypass the need for WiFi so that I can use this program outside of a WiFi hot spot?

Answer (score 0):

where is the server, i think you should provide server ip and port where the server is deployed, and there will b need of any connection of internet it depends on you.

Comment: The IP and port of the server as well as location doesn't really make a difference. It works with WiFi, it doesn't work without WiFi. You don't need the IP nor the port to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you won't use wifi connection for communicating, if you are using LAN or DSL connection than you have to provide new IP address of the server and port to the client meanns Socket(IP,PORT).